# Features selection using F-score for multiclass classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

I'm going to implement a feature selection algorithm, and I plan to use the F-score for because of its simplicity. The problem is that, the F-score is used for binary classification. **How can it be extended for multi-class classification?**

My idea is to use one-vs-all method. That is, if I have `k` classes, I would generate `k` F-scores for each of these (by taking only one feature at a time and calculate the F-score against all others) and then just take the average. **Would this be a good approach?**

Answer (score 1):

F-score tends to be very similar to likes of t and Kruskal-Wallis tests, when it comes to feature ranking. So, one solution can be using multi-level alternatives of t-test, e.g., ANOVA or their non-parametric versions.